# How can I update state after sorting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need update state after sort by salary

```
state = {
    workers: [
        {name: 'Bob', surname: 'Meljanski', salary: 5140},
        {name: 'Michel', surname: 'Hensson', salary: 5420},
        {name: 'Jane', surname: 'Mitchel', salary: 2054}
}

startSort = () => {
    const arr = this.state.workers.slice();

    arr[2].name = 'Mike';
    var kk = [...arr].sort((a,b) => (a.salary>b.salary)*2-1);

    this.setState(kk);
    console.log(kk);
}
```

by result. state renders without sorting. How can I do correctly? sorry for my english

Answer (score 8):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) accepts an object (the new state object)  or a function (an updater which will run when react actually updates the state, mostly used when the next state is depended on the previous state, like toggles etc), you passed to it an array.

You can try this:

```
 this.setState({workers: kk});
```